# old boot option still exist after format

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot

I have window 8 operating system. Before window 8 I use windows 7 and Ubuntu.
So, I have install Ubuntu “up” windows 7 without making any partition, the Ubuntu make it when I install it through window 7.  When I format my pc putting windows 8 in boot screen I have two option window 8 and Ubuntu. But I have not access to Ubuntu, the boot files has deleted, as is evident. However, I still have this two option.  So, the Ubuntu option exists with no reason? How can I remove the Ubuntu option in boot screen? I have no partition in my pc.  Any ideas?

I hope I described clear enough my problem.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Need to post this question on either superuser or the Ubuntu sister-site: http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: The Hiren's boot CD has a lot of tools which allow you to solve this kind of issues. Look here under the "MBR Tools" section: http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd

Answer (score 0):

Sound like the boot options are stored in UEFI.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to use [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) 
The other ways is to use MSConfig.
Just pres Start, type msconfig hit enter. Go to boot and you have there all your boot entries.